# No funciona la sentencia WHERE con un campo VARCHAR

Tags: python, sql, base-de-datos

Estoy comenzando en la programacion!. Quiero crear una función que sea el comando de un botón que me muestre en mi interfaz de usuario (utilizando la libreria tkinter de python) los datos de un registro, me funciona bien con los campos que son de tipo integer, pero no con los campos de tipo varchar, que son los que quiero usar

En el codigo tengo 4 entrys, quiero que en el de producto al colocar el nombre del producto y presionar un boton me salga la info de dicho producto almacenada en la base de datos, esto lo puedo hacer con el campo ID que es integer pero no con el campo producto que es varchar.

Este es todo el codigo, el error ocurre en la funcion def informacion_prod en la zona de funciones un poco antes de la mitad del codigo.

```py
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox
import sqlite3

root=Tk()

#-------------------------------------------------BBDD---------------------------------------------------------
def iniciar_base_de_datos():

    base_de_datos_productos_zorena = sqlite3.connect("productos_zorena")
    mi_cursor=base_de_datos_productos_zorena.cursor()

    try:
        mi_cursor.execute("""CREATE TABLE PRODUCTOS(
            ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
            PRODUCTO VARCHAR(100),
            PRECIO INTEGER,
            UNIDADES VARCHAR(20)
            )""")

        messagebox.showinfo("Creacion de base de datos", "La base de datos ha sido creada exitosamente!")

    except:
        messagebox.showwarning("Intento de conexion a la base de datos", "La base de datos ya ha sido creada!")

    base_de_datos_productos_zorena.commit()
    base_de_datos_productos_zorena.close()

#----------------------------------------------FUNCIONES-------------------------------------------------------
def boton_menu_salir():

    mensaje = messagebox.askquestion("Salir de aplicacion", "Desea salir de la aplicacion?")
    if mensaje=="yes":
        root.destroy()

def boton_menu_limpiar():

    valor_ID.set("")
    valor_producto.set("")
    valor_precio.set("")
    valor_unidades.set("")

def informacion_Prod():

    base_de_datos_productos_zorena = sqlite3.connect("productos_zorena")
    mi_cursor=base_de_datos_productos_zorena.cursor()

    mi_cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM PRODUCTOS WHERE PRODUCTO=" + valor_producto.get())
    info_producto=mi_cursor.fetchall()

    for i in info_producto:
        valor_ID.set(i[0])
        valor_producto.set(i[1])
        valor_precio.set(i[2])
        valor_unidades.set(i[3])

    base_de_datos_productos_zorena.commit()

def agregar_Prod():

    conexion = sqlite3.connect("productos_zorena")
    mi_cursor=conexion.cursor()

    datos=valor_producto.get(), valor_precio.get(), valor_unidades.get()

    mi_cursor.execute("INSERT INTO PRODUCTOS VALUES(NULL,?,?,?)",(datos))
    messagebox.showinfo("Agregar productos", "Producto agregado exitosamente!")

    conexion.commit()

def borrar_Prod():

    conexion = sqlite3.connect("productos_zorena")
    mi_cursor=conexion.cursor()

    mi_cursor.execute("DELETE FROM PRODUCTOS WHERE ID=" + valor_ID.get())
    messagebox.showinfo("Elimicar registro", "El producto se ha eliminado de la base de datos!")

    conexion.commit()

def actualizar_prod():

    conexion = sqlite3.connect("productos_zorena")
    mi_cursor=conexion.cursor()

    datos=valor_producto.get(), valor_precio.get(), valor_unidades.get()

    mi_cursor.execute("UPDATE PRODUCTOS SET PRODUCTO = ?, PRECIO = ?, UNIDADES = ? WHERE ID=" + valor_ID.get(), (datos))
    messagebox.showinfo("Actualizacion de productos", "Producto modificado exitosamente!")

    conexion.commit()

#-------------------------------------------------MENU---------------------------------------------------------
menu_principal=Menu(root)
root.config(menu=menu_principal)

boton_acceso=Menu(menu_principal, tearoff=0)
menu_principal.add_cascade(menu=boton_acceso, label="Acceso")
boton_acceso.add_command(label="Conectar", command=iniciar_base_de_datos)
boton_acceso.add_separator()
boton_acceso.add_command(label="Salir", command=boton_menu_salir)

boton_limpiar=Menu(menu_principal, tearoff=0)
menu_principal.add_cascade(menu=boton_limpiar, label="Limpiar")
boton_limpiar.add_command(label="Limpiar campos", command=boton_menu_limpiar)

#------------------------------------------------ENTRYS--------------------------------------------------------
frame_entrys=Frame(root)
frame_entrys.pack()

valor_ID=StringVar()
valor_producto=StringVar()
valor_precio=StringVar()
valor_unidades=StringVar()

Label(frame_entrys, text="ID").grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="e", pady=10, padx=10)
Entry(frame_entrys, textvariable=valor_ID).grid(row=0, column=1, padx=10)

Label(frame_entrys, text="Producto").grid(row=1, column=0, sticky="e", pady=10, padx=10)
Entry(frame_entrys, textvariable=valor_producto).grid(row=1, column=1, padx=10)

Label(frame_entrys, text="Precio").grid(row=2, column=0, sticky="e", pady=10, padx=10)
Entry(frame_entrys, textvariable=valor_precio).grid(row=2, column=1, padx=10)

Label(frame_entrys, text="Unidades", justify="r").grid(row=3, column=0, sticky="e", pady=10, padx=10)
Entry(frame_entrys, textvariable=valor_unidades).grid(row=3, column=1, padx=10)

#-----------------------------------------------BOTONES--------------------------------------------------------
frame_botones=Frame(root)
frame_botones.pack()

Button(frame_botones, text="Informacion Prod.", width=15, command=informacion_Prod).grid(row=0, column=0, pady=25, padx=10)

Button(frame_botones, text="Actualizar Prod.", width=15, command=actualizar_prod).grid(row=0, column=1, pady=25, padx=10)

Button(frame_botones, text="Agregar Prod.", width=15, command=agregar_Prod).grid(row=0, column=2, pady=25, padx=10)

Button(frame_botones, text="Borrar Prod.", width=15, command=borrar_Prod).grid(row=0, column=3, pady=25, padx=10)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Los valores `VARCHAR` necesitan ir entre comillas vamos. en vez de `"SELECT * FROM PRODUCTOS WHERE PRODUCTO=" + valor_producto.get()` sería algo como `"SELECT * FROM PRODUCTOS WHERE PRODUCTO='" + valor_producto.get()+"'"`

Comment: Las busquedas de cadenas en cualquier motor de base de datos hechas a través de un signo = hace una validacion literal, si haces un like con % entonces busca parcial, debes de ver que es lo que estás intentando obtener

Comment: Muchas gracias problema resuelto! aun no tengo muy claro el tema de la concatenación y el uso de las comillas en las bases de datos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Al realizar consultas con valores de tipo alfanuméricos o varchar tienes que colocar el parámetro entre comillas ya que así se indica el inicio y fin del parámetro. Te pueden ayudar estos 2 casos:

Para obtener un dato exacto:

```
("SELECT * FROM PRODUCTOS WHERE PRODUCTO = '" + valor_producto.get() + "'")
```

Para llenar una lista:

```
("SELECT * FROM PRODUCTOS WHERE PRODUCTO LIKE '%" + valor_producto.get() + "%'")
```

Espero te sirva, agradecería tu respuesta. Saludos!